# Java how to handle 2-Factor Authentication with LDAP

Tags: java, authentication, ldap

I used the below code to LDAP authenticate and works fine. However, if I turn on SMS authentication on the LDAP server I get the SMS but how do I modify the below code to supply the SMS code?

```
  FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
  Properties p = new Properties();
  p.load(reader);

  DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(p);

  SearchControls controls = new SearchControls();
  controls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
  controls.setCountLimit(1);   
  controls.setTimeLimit(5000); 

  String searchString = "(sAMAccountName=" + p.getProperty("USERNAME") + ")";
  NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> results = ctx.search("", searchString, controls);
  if (results.hasMore()) {
     SearchResult result = (SearchResult) results.next();

     Attribute dnAttr = attrs.get("distinguishedName");
     String dn = (String) dnAttr.get();
     p.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, dn);

     System.out.print("password: ");
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
     String passwd = br.readLine();

     p.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, passwd);

     new InitialDirContext(p); // Exception will be thrown on Invalid case
     System.out.println("Login successful");
  }
```

Comment: You just make it up as a random number with enough digits. Nothing to do with LDAP whatsoever, by definition.

Comment: @user207421 im authenticating using LDAP to Multi-Factor-Authentication (MFA) so the MFA is doing the two factor...

Comment: So LDAP is one factor and the SMS is another factor. They are independent. That's the whole point. Otherwise it isn't MFA. So your SMS number has nothing to do with LDAP.